# working around oracle bind variables

Tags: oracle11g

I am just trying my hands on Bind Variables. But got stuck on this piece. Not able to compile it :-

```
  VARIABLE b_basic_percent NUMBER
  VARIABLE b_pf_percent NUMBER

 DECLARE 
   v_today DATE:=SYSDATE;        
   v_tomorrow v_today%TYPE;

 BEGIN 
   v_tomorrow:=v_today +1; 
   :b_basic_percent:=45; 
   :b_pf_percent:=12;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' Hello World '); 
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TODAY IS : '|| v_today); 
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TOMORROW IS : ' || v_tomorrow); 

   PRINT  b_basic_percent 
   PRINT b_pf_percent

END;
```

Can some one please help me to understand where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PRINT` is a SQL*Plus command, not a PL/SQL command. As such, it should come **after** the PL/SQL block (in much the same way as the `VARIABLE` happened before the block), like so:

```
variable b_basic_percent number
variable b_pf_percent number

declare 
  v_today date:=sysdate;        
  v_tomorrow v_today%type;

begin 
  v_tomorrow := v_today + 1; 
  :b_basic_percent := 45; 
  :b_pf_percent := 12;
  dbms_output.put_line(' Hello World '); 
  dbms_output.put_line('TODAY IS : '|| to_char(v_today, 'dd Mon yyyy')); 
  dbms_output.put_line('TOMORROW IS : ' || to_char(v_tomorrow, 'dd Mon yyyy')); 

end;
/

print b_basic_percent 
print b_pf_percent


 Hello World 
TODAY IS : 05 Nov 2015
TOMORROW IS : 06 Nov 2015

b_basic_percent
---------------
             45

b_pf_percent
------------
          12
```

Comment: #Boneist:- Thanks ! It worked and also for sharing the info.